# setTimeout() тормозит браузер

Tags: javascript

Перед вами код, который при загрузке страницы рубит нужный текст на отдельные символы, а при вызове функции textAnimate() каждой букве которая теперь является отдельный элементом присвоится класс в котором прописана анимация.
Суть проблемы такова в Хроме и в опере все почти норм, а в мазиле вообще капец, 
теперь конкретней, когда вызывается textAnimate(), она должна успеть присвоить всем элементам (то есть буквам), нужный класс примерно за 600ms с маленьким хвостиком так как какое то время еще потеряется на само выполнение, которое на любом из перечисленных браузеров получается примерно 150ms. Но вот проблема в том что такая общая цифра 150ms получается только если не использовать setTimeout() а в место него каждый раз без ожидания вызывать showLetter(), тогда вся операция проходит за 100-150ms и все буквы получают класс фактически одновременно, и в таком случае нужного эффекта анимации уже нет, а когда использую setTimeout()даже с нулевым значением в качестве задержки время выполнения в хроме и опере примерно 1100ms, плохо ну ещё куда не шло, но в мазиле около 2500ms, а при таком раскладе анимашка уже совсем не та(.
Прошу у знающих людей совета, как выйти на нужное время, а также почему так происходит что не так с setTimeout().
Спасибо за ваши ответы.

```
`        var timeout = 600;
      (function(){
        var
          descriptions = $('.slider__image-description'),
          titles = descriptions.find('h2'),
          technologists = descriptions.find('p');
          //функция подготовит текст к анимации порубает на отдельные буквы все что надо
        function fraction(e){
          e.forEach(function(item){
            item.each(function(){
              var that = $(this);
              var string = that.text();
              that.html(string.replace(/./g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>'));
            });
          }); 
          return;
        }
        fraction([titles, technologists]);
      })();

      function textAnimate(that){
        var
          letterList = that.find('.letter'),
          listLength = letterList.length,
          i = 0;

        (function showLetter(){
          var currentLetter = $(letterList[i]).html();
         //если это пробел зададим ему фиксированную ширину иначе потом он сплющиться 
          if (currentLetter === ' ') {
            var letterWidth = $(letterList[i]).width();
          //если ширина пробела = 0, значит это конец строки и нужно вставить елемент переноса строки
            if (letterWidth == 0) {
              $(letterList[i]).after('<br>');
            }
            $(letterList[i]).width(letterWidth);
          }else{
            //добавим клас с анимацией
            $(letterList[i]).addClass('showLetter');
          }
          i++;
          setTimeout(function(){
            if (i < listLength) {
              showLetter();
            } 
          }, timeout/listLength);
        })();
      }`
```

Comment: Почему бы на стадии разбития текста на символы не задавать просто `transition-delay`, если это "класс с анимацией"?

Comment: все гениальное просто transition-delay,  как я сам не додумался только не transition-delay а animation-delay, но не суть, спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так, метод построен на css анимации, где `setTimeout` используется лишь для того, что бы задать определенный класс контейнеру который начнет эту анимацию:

```js
$(function() {
  textAnimate();
});

function textAnimate() {
  let processedText = '';
  const $textBlock = $('.text'),
    text = $textBlock.text(),
    textChars = text.match(/./gi),
    textCharsLength = textChars.length,
    animationDuration = 10;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < textCharsLength; i++) {
      let delay = (i / textCharsLength * animationDuration).toFixed(3);
    
      processedText += '' +
      '<span class="letter" style="' +
        '-webkit-transition-delay: ' + delay + 's;' +
        '-o-transition-delay: ' + delay + 's;' +
        'transition-delay: ' + delay + 's;"' +
      '>' + textChars[i] + '</span>'
    }  
    
    $textBlock.html(processedText);
    
    setTimeout(function() { $textBlock.addClass('show'); }, 1);
}
```

```css
.letter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .1s;
       -o-transition: opacity .1s;
          transition: opacity .1s;
}

.text.show .letter {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```